# Не получается присвоить переменной значение, которое является результатом работы функции

Tags: javascript

Есть массив чисел и для каждого нужно найти его факториал.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Для этого я сделал 2 функции: первая находит факториал, а вторая работает с массивом

```
let n = 4;

function factorial(n) {
    let i = 1, sum = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum *= i;
    }
    return sum;
}

function processArray(arr, factorial) {
    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++) {
        arr[i] = factorial(arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

В функции по работе с массивом я пытаюсь присвоить значению `arr[i]` результат работы функции `factorial(n)`, но почему-то это так не работает. Буду благодарен, если кто-то объяснит мне, где я сделал ошибку.

Comment: а как вы вызываете `processArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте буквы местами:

```
arr.lenght -> arr.length
```

Comment: Да, действительно, виной всему опечатка. Спасибо!